# Node TypeError: checkURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does it produce a TypeError checkURL is not a function. i searched few older question too but couldn't figure out why it shows the error.

```
const Server = {
    checkURL: function(url, matchWith) {
        return url === matchWith;
    },

    respond: function(res, status, cType, data ) {
        res.writeHead(status, {
            'Content-Type': cType,
        })
        res.write(data)
        res.end() 
    },

    streams: function(req, res) {
        if (this.checkURL(req, '/')) {
            this.respond(res, 200, 'text/html', `<h2>HELLO</h2>`)
        }
    },
    init: function(PORT) {
        require('http')
            .createServer(this.streams)
            .listen(PORT, () => {
                console.log(`Listening on <${PORT}>`)
            })
        return this
    }
}

module.exports = Server
```

Comment: Try: `....createServer(this.streams.bind(this))`.

Comment: no good. still doesn't work

Comment: Is `checkURL` called from somewhere other then the `streams` function ?

Comment: no its only called in the streams function

Comment: Then the change that I've suggested should solve the problem. Are you sure you're getting the same error after this change and not some other error ?

Comment: yeah 100% sure.

Comment: Oh, actually, it matters how you call `init`, you'll also have to set that function's context to `Server`.

Comment: Try: `....createServer(this.streams.bind(Server))`.

Comment: I test your above code, but there is not error that you mentioned.

Comment: sorry @Titus you were right. i ran it before saving. thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help, good luck.